# Execute a command every time Terminal is open

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, .bash-profile

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 and I'd like to configure my terminal, so that every time a new tab/window is open, it executes the following command automatically and right away.

```
 /bin/bash --login
```

How could I achieve this? On OSX with iTerm 2 there is an option to run a command on start. I guess here I should achieve this thru some kind of dotfile...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? When you open a new terminal, this command is already executed.

Comment: No its not. I need this because of a bug in some development environment I use. The `--login` flag is crucial.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add the command to your `~/.bashrc`. Technically, you *should* be able to add to `~/.profile` as well, from `man bash`, `INVOCATION` documentation:

> If bash is invoked with the name `sh`, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of `sh` as  closely  as  possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.  When invoked as an interactive login shell, or a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first attempts  to  read  and  execute commands  from  `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, in that order.

Also:

> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection, as when executed by the remote shell daemon, usually `rshd`, or the secure shell daemon `sshd`. If bash determines  it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, if these files exist and are readable.

So, this means that if you're logged in locally you should be OK using `~/.profile`; but, if you ssh to systems then you'll want to use `~/.bashrc`. `~/.bashrc` also applies when logged in locally; so, it has just become convention to use that.

Comment: in my case, run `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` and added the command

Answer (score 5):

Try:

- In terminal, Edit > Preferences > Tab Title and command > **Run a custom command of my shell**.

[image]

Or

- `gnome-terminal --tab -e "your command"` to open a new tab.

More informations: [ManPage Gnome-terminal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html)

Comment: Actually, just checking the `run command as login shell` fixed my problem.