# How can I run a bash script everytime I open my terminal?

Tags: bash, arch-linux

I want to run a bash script every time my terminal opens. I'm kind of new to Arch Linux, so I'm not an expert on it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked and answered many times. In short, add whatever you wish to execute to your `~/.bashrc` file. Please refer to the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/591321/execute-a-command-every-time-terminal-is-open) question for more info.

Comment: You are correct.  It might be you dont have enough reputation for close votes, as one of the options is "Duplicate"